# Android Shared Element Transitions between two ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have an item view that displays a `ViewPager` with images of that item and some other information. When the user taps one of the `ViewPager`'s images, I'd like there to be a transition between the image on the first screen and the same image on another `ViewPager` in a new `Activity`.

So far, I've managed to get the basic functionality working but there are a couple of key things that do not work as expected:

1. The transition from `ViewPager` A to the second `Activity` with `ViewPager` B only works when tapping the image at index 0 or 1 in `ViewPager` A.
2. There *is* a return animation when pressing back from `ViewPager` B in the new `Activity` - as long as I do not swipe to another image so the transition is from the full screen mode I'd be displaying in `ViewPager` B to the same image in `ViewPager` A. When swiping to another image and pressing back - there's no animation.

Number 1 is happening because the first couple of pages of the `ViewPager` are instantiated when it's created so the `instantiateItem` method of the `Adapter` gets called for each of these and this is where I'm setting the `transitionName`. 
This is proven by the fact that calling this on the `ViewPager` makes that issue go away and the entry animation works on all screens:

`detailPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(largeNumber);`

Obviously this is unsustainable, I'd much rather *not* have such a high off screen limit.

My question is twofold:

**How do I achieve the animation for each `ViewPager` item without keeping all the pages in memory via the above hack?**

**How can I ensure that a return transition takes place when swiping to another page in `ViewPager` B?**

I've included my code below:

**ItemActivity**

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String ITEM_TAG = "item_tag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_fragment_container);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        attachFragment();
    }
}

private void attachFragment() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, ItemFragment.newInstance(), ITEM_TAG)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data);
    ItemFragment fragment = (ItemFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ITEM_TAG);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onReenter(data);
    }
}}
```

**ItemFragment - This is where the first ViewPager is**

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.MyListener {

public static final String EXTRA_STARTING_ALBUM_POSITION = "extra_starting_item_position";
public static final String EXTRA_CURRENT_ALBUM_POSITION = "extra_current_item_position";
public static final String[] IMAGE_NAMES = {"One", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
private static final int FULL_SCREEN_CODE = 1234;

private Unbinder unbinder;
private Bundle tempReenterState;
private final SharedElementCallback callback = new SharedElementCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
        if (tempReenterState != null) {
            int startingPosition = tempReenterState.getInt(EXTRA_STARTING_ALBUM_POSITION);
            int currentPosition = tempReenterState.getInt(EXTRA_CURRENT_ALBUM_POSITION);
            if (startingPosition != currentPosition) {

                String newTransitionName = IMAGE_NAMES[currentPosition];
                View newSharedElement = detailPager.findViewWithTag(newTransitionName);
                if (newSharedElement != null) {
                    names.clear();
                    names.add(newTransitionName);
                    sharedElements.clear();
                    sharedElements.put(newTransitionName, newSharedElement);
                }
            }

            tempReenterState = null;
        } else {
            View navigationBar = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);
            View statusBar = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
            if (navigationBar != null) {
                names.add(navigationBar.getTransitionName());
                sharedElements.put(navigationBar.getTransitionName(), navigationBar);
            }
            if (statusBar != null) {
                names.add(statusBar.getTransitionName());
                sharedElements.put(statusBar.getTransitionName(), statusBar);
            }
        }
    }
};

private List<String> images = Arrays.asList("http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-9/data/images/1293441583_nature_forest_morning_in_the_forest_015232_.jpg",
        "http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-18/data1/images/hongkong1081704.jpg",
        "http://www.irishtimes.com/polopoly_fs/1.2614603.1461003507!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_620_330/image.jpg",
        "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/sky/sky-05.jpg");

@BindView(R.id.detail_pager)
ViewPager detailPager;

public static ItemFragment newInstance() {
    return new ItemFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_detail, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback(getActivity(), callback);
    detailPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), images, this));

}

@Override
public void goFullScreen(final int position, View view) {
    Intent intent = FullScreenActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), position, images);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FULL_SCREEN_CODE, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), view, view.getTransitionName()).toBundle());
}

public void onReenter(Intent data) {
    tempReenterState = new Bundle(data.getExtras());
    int startingPosition = tempReenterState.getInt(EXTRA_STARTING_ALBUM_POSITION);
    int currentPosition = tempReenterState.getInt(EXTRA_CURRENT_ALBUM_POSITION);
    if (startingPosition != currentPosition) {
        detailPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition, false);
    }
    ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(getActivity());
    detailPager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(getActivity());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (unbinder != null) {
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

}

**FullScreenActivity - This is where the second ViewPager is housed**

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final SharedElementCallback callback = new SharedElementCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
        if (mIsReturning) {
            if (currentImage == null) {
                // If shared element is null, then it has been scrolled off screen and
                // no longer visible. In this case we cancel the shared element transition by
                // removing the shared element from the shared elements map.
                names.clear();
                sharedElements.clear();
            } else if (selectedIndex != mCurrentPosition) {
                // If the user has swiped to a different ViewPager page, then we need to
                // remove the old shared element and replace it with the new shared element
                // that should be transitioned instead.
                names.clear();
                names.add(currentImage.getTransitionName());
                sharedElements.clear();
                sharedElements.put(currentImage.getTransitionName(), currentImage);
            }
        }
    }
};

private boolean mIsReturning;
private int mCurrentPosition;
private int selectedIndex;


private static final String ARG_PRESELECTED_INDEX = "arg_preselected_index";
private static final String ARG_GALLERY_IMAGES = "arg_gallery_images";

public static final String KEY_SELECTED_IMAGE_INDEX = "key_selected_image_index";

public static final String KEY_RETAINED_IMAGES = "key_retained_images";
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDEX = 0;

private List<String> images;
private ImageAdapter adapter;
private ImageView currentImage;

@BindView(R.id.full_screen_pager)
ViewPager viewPager;

public static Intent newIntent(@NonNull final Context context, final int selectedIndex, @NonNull final List<String> images) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_PRESELECTED_INDEX, selectedIndex);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(ARG_GALLERY_IMAGES, new ArrayList<>(images));
    return intent;
}

@CallSuper
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_full_screen);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
    ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback(this, callback);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectedIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra(ARG_PRESELECTED_INDEX, 0);
        mCurrentPosition = selectedIndex;
        images = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(ARG_GALLERY_IMAGES);
    } else {
        selectedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_IMAGE_INDEX);
        images = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(KEY_RETAINED_IMAGES);
    }
    setupViewPager(selectedIndex, images);
}

private void setupViewPager(final int selectedIndex, List<String> images) {
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, images);
    viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedIndex);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    mCurrentPosition = position;
                }
            });
            ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(FullScreenActivity.this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void finishAfterTransition() {
    mIsReturning = true;
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTING_ALBUM_POSITION, selectedIndex);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_CURRENT_ALBUM_POSITION, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    super.finishAfterTransition();
}

private class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final List<String> images;
    private ImageLoader<ImageView> imageLoader;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> images) {
        this.imageLoader = new PicassoImageLoader(context);
        this.images = images;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_image, container, false);
        imageView.setTransitionName(IMAGE_NAMES[position]);
        imageView.setTag(IMAGE_NAMES[position]);
        imageLoader.loadImage(images.get(position), imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        currentImage = (ImageView) object;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

}

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private final List<String> images;
private final MyListener listener;

private ImageLoader<ImageView> imageLoader;

public interface MyListener {
    void goFullScreen(final int position, View selected);
}

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> images, MyListener listener) {
    this.imageLoader = new PicassoImageLoader(context);
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.images = images;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item_image_thing, container, false);
    imageView.setTransitionName(IMAGE_NAMES[position]);
    imageView.setTag(IMAGE_NAMES[position]);
    if (listener != null) {
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.goFullScreen(position, imageView);
            }
        });
    }
    imageLoader.loadImage(images.get(position), imageView);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

}

**ImageLoader**

```
public interface ImageLoader<T extends ImageView> {

void loadImage(@NonNull final Uri imageSource, @NonNull final T imageView);

void loadImage(@NonNull final String imageSource, @NonNull final T imageView);
```

}

**PicassoImageLoader**

```
public class PicassoImageLoader implements ImageLoader {

private final Context context;

public PicassoImageLoader(@NonNull final Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void loadImage(@NonNull Uri imageSource, @NonNull ImageView imageView) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageSource).into(imageView);
}

@Override
public void loadImage(@NonNull String imageSource, @NonNull ImageView imageView) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageSource).into(imageView);
}
```

}

**XML Layouts**

fragment_image_detail.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/detail_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some other descriptive text about things"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_full_screen.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/full_screen_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

pager_item_thing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
```

full_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: So, as I understand, your **first** `ViewPager` is not fullscreen? What are the width and the height of its item?

Comment: @rom4ek Correct. The first one is not full screen. The width is set to `match_parent` and the height is set to 390dp - though this height is just for the sake of example. I've updated the question to include the XML layouts for both screens.

Comment: What about `pager_item_image_thing` layout?

Comment: @rom4ek I've included a couple more layouts